# Okhttp always retrying failed connection

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

If I create a request and that request returns a `4xx` error Retrofit/Okhttp keeps retrying the request. I have set `retryOnConnectionFailure` to false and set a timeout of 15 seconds but that all seems to be ignored. did I miss something?

```
private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE))
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    Request request = chain.request()
                            .newBuilder()
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }).build();
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Gson gson){
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(OkHttpLogger.getClient());
        if(gson != null){
            builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        }else{
            builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
```

I am using retrofit `2.3.0` and okhttp version `3.8.1`

**Edit**

One thing I do see is that if I set a timeout of 5 seconds it works perfectly keeps retrying for 5 seconds then gives me a failure but if I bump it up to 10 seconds it just keeps going and finally stops around 2 minutes.

Comment: Is your interceptor responsible for allowing the requests to continue? You're right in implementing `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)` as the known switch for disabling silent request retries.

Comment: @M.Palsich removing the interceptor has no effect. One thing I do see is that if I set a timeout of 5 seconds it works perfectly keeps retrying for 5 seconds then gives me a failure but if I bump it up to 10 seconds it just keeps going and finally stops around 2 minutes.

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator that exists within an environment having its own setting for TCP SYN retries? For example, Linux can set its own TCP SYN retry limit.

Comment: Nope it's on a physical device and happens on all devices I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `retryOnConnectionFailure` does not apply to `408` responses so it will still retry those automatically

Comment: So how someone can disable the retry even on 408 error?

Comment: Can anyone share the http error code applicable for  retryOnConnectionFailure

Comment: @tyczj can you share the documentation

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you, I use Retrofit in Application Class and use that class in Manifest file as application name tag

```
public final class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

public static Retrofit retrofit;
public static String base_URL = "http://mds.devsiteurl.com/";

public static final String TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

private static Application mInstance;

public static synchronized Application getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInstance = this;
    MultiDex.install(this);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
}
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

And in Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mds.foundation.mdsfoundation">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_apis_keys" />

    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CenterOfExcellenceActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

And finally gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mds.foundation.mdsfoundation"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true  //this line is important
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

//refrofit 
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: This does not help, its basically what I have

Comment: Have you extends `MultiDexApplication` in your Application Class?

Comment: yes but that is unrelated to using okhttp and retrofit

Comment: Why this should help?

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating your own retryOnConnectionFailure interceptor:

here is code in kotlin:

```
open class MaxRetryCountInterceptor(private val retryLimit: Int) : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        var response = chain.proceed(request)
        var tryCount = 0

        while (!response.isSuccessful && tryCount < retryLimit) {
            tryCount++
            response = chain.proceed(request)
        }

        return response
    }
}
```

`response.isSuccessful` is successful only when code is between `200..300`